# Xcode Error: Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, mapkit

After doing some searching and editing, I can't seem to find a solution to fixing this error. I'm trying to link my location search results with a table to display the search results in a list-form.

I have my map with the details button linked with a UIViewController called 'FirstViewController.' My results table is linked with a UITableViewController called 'ResultsTableViewController.' My prototype cells are linked with a UITableViewCell called 'ResultsTableCell' which is also where my outlets are located.

Here are the 2 separate errors:

> Illegal Configuration: The nameLabel outlet from the ResultsTableViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.
>
> Illegal Configuration: The phoneLabel outlet from the ResultsTableViewController to the UILabel is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

I've read other people's posts with the same problem, tried to fix them accordingly and I'm still getting the same error.

Here is the code for populating the cell, located in my ResultsTableViewController.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultsTableCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let row = indexPath.row
    let item = mapItems[row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
    cell.phoneLabel.text = item.phoneNumber
    return cell
}
```

The code in my ResultsTableCell class:

```
import UIKit

class ResultsTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: You need to connect your outlet to the custom cell not to the view controller

Comment: That's what I've done already.

"@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!"
    
 "@IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!"

Comment: Show your custom cell and how you populate your table view

Comment: Show  ResultsTableCell class

Comment: Added that to the main post as well.

Comment: Have you selected your ResultsTableCell at your interface builder and then at your inspector selected the Custom Cell dropdown menu and selected ResultsTableCell?

Comment: Yes. The view controller class is set to ResultsTableViewController and the prototype cell class is set to ResultsTableCell.

Comment: You probably did not delete the first connection outlet you've made. This message only occurs if you connect it to the view controller.

Comment: Note: Even if you delete the code if you right click your cell you would still see the old connection.

Comment: Here are my current connections: http://i.imgur.com/XU6GC7v.png

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This message only occurs if you connect it to the view controller. As I have already commented, you probably did not delete the first connection outlet you've made to your view controller. Even if you delete the IBOutlet code from your view controller you still need to right click it and delete the old connection that probably still there. After deleting it the error message will go away.

Comment: Both of my error codes had 2 instances, after right clicking on the view controller and deleting the connections, the second instance of each error went away. But there are still 2 of the same errors that I can't seem to fix.

Comment: I re-loaded my Xcode and the errors disappeared, but upon building the app there seems to be a problem with this line of code:

    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
            userLocation.location.coordinate, 2000, 2000)

It is highlighted green with the error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION"

Comment: @Alec feel free to open another question. The comments area is not intended to be used for secondary questions not related to the original question. BTW Don't forget to accept the answer as it might help another user with a similar issue. Let me know once you have posted your new question so I can take a look at it also.

Comment: I've posted my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018421/xcode-swift-thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-on-mkcoordinateregionmakewithdistan

Comment: This worked  Leo, thank you for mentioning view Controller

Answer (score 1):

this issue happen when you delete view from your class but still have reference in your view

here is example I remove back outlet reference from my class but my view still keep the reference **Notice yellow rectangle** just delete it by click at x

if you want to know how to reach this view , open your storyboard , right click at top left yellow it will show this dialog

[image]